# Columns are not consistent with same CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the exact coding in my html for each of these columns and I'm not sure what I've changed in my css to make the columns all look so different. The left column is the style and positioning that I want. I don't understand how all the more buttons are different and how the more button on the right is completely separate from the grey box even though they are in the same div...I'm new at this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

I will add a jsfiddle to show all of the code and I'll add a portion of the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/40bnatg3/

Also here is a picture of the problem:
   [image]

```
<div class="column-center">
<div id= "middle-box">
    <h2> Objectives</h2>
     <img class="img" src="techpic4.jpg" alt="example web page" width="200" height="200" />
    <p >Upon successful completion of the course the student will:
1) Demonstrate competency in the following computer software applications or 
practices;
a. HyperText Markup Language (HTML5)
b. Cascading Style Sheets (CSS3)
c. Photoshop
d. IFirefox, Chrome, Safari, IE 
e. FTP clients (Fetch, Filezilla, etc.)
2. Design web pages of various complexities. 
3. Understand terminology used in web publishing.
4. Discuss the importance of graphic applications and their relationship to the graph
-
ic communications industry.

<br>

<a id="button2" href="msum.css" class="more">More</a>
</p>
 </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Please share the complete HTML code of these three columns and related CSS definitions.

Comment: just did sorry I completely forgot to link the JsFiddle @mertyildrian

Answer (score 1):

Remove **position:relative** from .column_center style class definition:

```
.column-center{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 1%;
    bottom: 18px;
}
```

Also, you will have to remove a br tag that is between left colum html and center column html in line 49.

Then you will have to change the **button1 id** definition to:

```
#button1{
    color:black;
    top: 35px;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 1%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

**Edit:**

I think it is cleaner for your code to remove all the css styles for #button1, #button2 and #button3 and just leave the style for class .more like this:

```
.more {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  color:black;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 20px;
  right: 31px;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have updated the jsfiddle and am still having issues with it... @Dez

Comment: Also do you know how I would bring the third column grey box down to match the others? @Dez

Comment: I updated my answer with the modifications to #button1 id selector in order to achieve the same position for "More" link tag.

Comment: yup I got that and it worked, but I'm still having troubles having the left one match those two. As in the white box matching them. I'll update my picture and the jsfiddle so you can see. @Dez

Comment: The main problem is you are overriding styles, so you better tidy up your css code a little bit. I suggest a quick solution for that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! With your comments I was able to figure it out! Thanks again!!! @Dez